# Gender for pronoun “personne”

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, genre

When we use *personne* as a noun, the gender is feminine:

> Il y a une personne **endormie** dans la salle, alors je ne veux pas **la** déranger.

If *personne* is used as a pronoun, is it correct that the gender should be masculine?

> Il n'y a personne **endormi** dans la salle, alors on peut l'utiliser.
>
> Personne n'est **parfait**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personne as a pronoun lose its feminine gender so both of your examples are correct. However, there are very rare cases where the feminine can be used:

Source [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/personne):

> Rem. 1. Personne n'a pas de marque de genre: Je ne connais **personne** d'aussi **heureux** que cette femme (Ac. 1935); Littré cite cependant: **Personne** n'était plus **belle** que Cléopâtre.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You would write : « Personne n’est parfait. » and « Cette personne n’est pas parfaite. »